# Carga de Informacion de datos uno por uno

Tags: android

Estoy programando una aplicación y en una pequeña sección de registro tengo de esta forma:

- Ingrese Numero 1
- Ingrese Numero 2

Ya arme el `.xml` con su respectivo `.java` y funciona. Pero necesito lo siguiente que cuando empiece hacer el 1 pedido de numero solo me aparesca "Ingrese Numero 1" una vez que lo cargue, automaticamente me aparesca el 2 pedido de numero "Ingrese Numero 2", este es el codigo .xml y .java

---

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_numero1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Ingrese 1 Numero"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_numero2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.118" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_numero2"
    android:layout_width="213dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Ingrese 2 Numero"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_numero1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
    android:onClick="Sumar"
    android:text="SUMAR"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_resultado"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_numero2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_resultado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="152dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="208dp"
    android:text="Resultado"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

y aqui el .java

```
 private EditText et1,et2;
 private TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numero2);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado);
}
public void Sumar(View view)
{
    String valor1=et1.getText().toString();
    String valor2=et2.getText().toString();
    int numero1=Integer.parseInt(valor1);
    int numero2=Integer.parseInt(valor2);
    int suma=numero1+numero2;
    String resultado=String.valueOf(suma);
    tv1.setText(resultado);
}
```

me anda bien  pero requiero esa parte de animacion, ire buscando sobre AlphaAnimation que me recomendaron. Edite el post para subir un ejemplo sencillo para evitar poner el codigo largo del .java y el .xml

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, para que la ayuda que te den sea basada en tu codigo. Y libreria para eso no es necesario. Debes tenes algun evento que detecte la condicion que tu quieras y luego coloque en visible tus demas componentes

Comment: Podrías usar AlphaAnimation para cada EditText y usar un AnimationListener para detectar cuando termina cada animación para iniciar la siguiente. Pero, como dice Ramiro, debes añadir tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: post editado, con un ejemplo mas sencillo

Answer (score 0):

Con listener para el primer EditText puedes controlar cuando el valor sea introducido o cambiado y así iniciar la animación para el segundo EditText

```
final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
et1.startAnimation(animation);
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et2.startAnimation(animation);
    }
});
```

Debes de indicar "invisible" en la propiedad del segundo EditText.

Comment: osea en el 1 EditText tengo que declarar un listener, y en el segundo un invisible???

Comment: Exacto, en el primer EditText añades el listener para detectar cuando el número sea introducido y en el xml, en la propiedad "visibility" del segundo EditText declaras "invisible"